What does "Juicy" mean?
Gurney communicates with the operator of the spice harvesting vehicle

Gurney: Juicy?
Man 1: Juicy, juicy. Well, it was nice knowing ya.
Gurney: Oh, yeah?
Man 1: Radar's clear. We're clear.

Gurney exits the spice harvester:

Gurney: Cooking time.

Gurney lands on the ground after flying and stretches out a hand to caress
the desert's gentle dunes:

Gurney: Juicy, juicy.

What does "Juicy" mean?

There's no ulterior meaning here. He just means that it's a profitable patch of Spice sand.

Juicy: (Adjective.)
Highly profitable
e.g. A juicy contract

